# c# openxml set up self running power point presentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on one demo application (Asp.net MVC) where i want to apply self running and transition time animation on existing Power Points. I wrote below code,

```
using (var templateFile = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/OurCompanyTeam.pptx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        templateFile.CopyTo(stream); 
        using (var presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(stream, true)) 
        {
            var presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;                            
            var presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;
            var slideList = new List<SlidePart>();                            

            foreach (SlideId slideID in presentation.SlideIdList)
            {
                var slide = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slideID.RelationshipId);
                Transition trns = new Transition();
                trns.Duration =  "2.5";
                trns.Speed = TransitionSpeedValues.Fast;
                slide.Slide.Transition = trns;
                slideList.Add(slide);
            }
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }
        byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);                        
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/output.pptx"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        ms.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

How could i improve this code to set up self running presentation?

Comment: Why do you need 2 memory streams?

Comment: @FortyTwo Do you have solution to my question?

Comment: You asked for improvements, here's one you don't need 2 memory streams. If something is not working as desired then provide more details, errors etc..

Answer (score 0):

The code in this answer will make any presentation(`.pptx`) a self running Slide Show (`.ppsx`).  It does the following items:

1. Puts the presentation in kiosk mode
2. Sets the `AdvanceAfterTime` attribute to 2 seconds for each slide
3. Change the Document type to Slide Show
4. Saves contents of `.pptx` to a new `.ppsx` file.

You can replace your code above with the following code.  Add a `_sourceFile` string local variable to save the full path to your file. Notes in the comments for the items above:

```
using (var templateFile = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/OurCompanyTeam.pptx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                templateFile.CopyTo(stream);
                using (var presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {
                    var presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
                    var presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;
                    var slideList = new List<SlidePart>();

                    foreach (SlideId slideID in presentation.SlideIdList)
                    {
                        var slidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slideID.RelationshipId);

                        AlternateContent alternateContent1 = slidePart.Slide.GetFirstChild<AlternateContent>();

                        if (alternateContent1 != null)
                        {
                            slidePart.Slide.RemoveAllChildren<AlternateContent>();
                        }

                            var trns1 = new Transition();
                            trns1.Duration = "2000";
                            trns1.AdvanceOnClick = false;
                            trns1.AdvanceAfterTime = "2000"; //ITEM #2
                            trns1.Speed = TransitionSpeedValues.Slow;

                            var alternateContent = new AlternateContent();
                            alternateContent.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");

                            AlternateContentChoice alternateContentChoice = new AlternateContentChoice() { Requires = "p14" };
                            alternateContentChoice.AddNamespaceDeclaration("p14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main");

                            alternateContentChoice.Append(trns1);
                            alternateContent.Append(alternateContentChoice);
                            slidePart.Slide.Append(alternateContent);
                    }

                    var presentationPropertiesPart = presentationPart.PresentationPropertiesPart;
                    var presentationProperties = presentationPropertiesPart.PresentationProperties;
                    presentationProperties.RemoveAllChildren<ShowProperties>();

                    presentationProperties.Append(NewShowProperties());

                    presentationDocument.ChangeDocumentType(PresentationDocumentType.Slideshow);  //ITEM #3

                }
                byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                FileStream file = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_sourceFile) + "/NewSlideShow.ppsx",
                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);  //ITEM #4
                ms.WriteTo(file);
                file.Close();
            }   
}
```

then add this method at the bottom of your class:

```
    private ShowProperties NewShowProperties()
    {
        var showProperties = new ShowProperties { Loop = true, ShowNarration = true };
        showProperties.Append(new KioskSlideMode());  //ITEM #1
        showProperties.Append(new SlideAll());
        showProperties.Append(new PresenterSlideMode());
        return showProperties;
    }
```

I've tested this to work on newly created PowerPoint 2013 and 2016 Presentations.  Double click on the `.ppsx` file and it will launch the self-running presentation.